# Looking for an extended version of Lightbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I am not sure how to put this, maybe I'm not able to search it properly I'm not sure what is it called but I am looking for a script which is a kind of an extended version of lightbox script. 
I want to place some images in my website which when clicked opens as lightbox and can go next and previous but the trick is the next images have to be sub pics of the pic which is displayed. 
So lets say I have "a" "b" "c" ....images shown on my website but when some clicks "a" the image "a" opens but then when he clicks next image {{ with the help of the lightbox script }}
he goes to "a.1" "a.2" ....and so on for image "b" ......
Can anyone help me finding this script I have seen i somewhere bu not sure of the search term.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery lightbox plugin should do just that, all you need to do is make sure all your images are added to the page in the order you want them to display in the lightbox, and then for the images you don't want shown on the page but, but shown in the lightbox (eg. a.1, a.2, a.3), add a class like:

```
class='noshow'
```

And a css rule of:

```
.noshow{display:none;}
```

However, this css rule will make the content completely inaccessible if javascript doesn't work, and should be set with the following jquery selector instead:

```
$('.noshow').css({'display':'none'});
```